# USB corrupted, how to proceed

Tags: usb, mount

While trying to install GRUB on an USB (because my PC wasn't recognizing it on boot), I ended up messing up and got a corrupted USB, I can't mount it, and trying to format it with GParted doesn't solve the problem either.

The message once I boot it is:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/lucas/Ubuntu 15.10 amd64:
Command-line `mount -t "iso9660" -o
"uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500"
"/dev/sdb1" "/media/lucas/Ubuntu 15.10 amd64"' exited with non-zero
exit status 32: mount: /dev/sdb1 is write-protected, mounting
read-only mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on
/dev/sdb1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

I need this USB soon and I don't know what to do, help!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to go! Thanks to this [guy](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/surviving-a-linux-filesystem-failures.html). And other research done prior.

1. Install GParted and turn the whole USB drive into a big *ext4*
   partition. Check the partition name (usually /dev/sdb1 or
   /dev/sdc1).
2. Use the code below on your Terminal.

   ```
   e2fsck -f -y /dev/sdb1
   ```

   *-f* goes for force-checking the partition and *-y* goes for answering "yes" to all questions automatically.

   - Disconnect the USB, wait some seconds and connect it again. It will
     mount!